# How to hide duplicate values from rows in sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008

I am trying to export table data to excel format.

My present view's select query give result like this ..

```
IDs  Column_A  Column_B  Column_C  Column_D   Column_E  
1    EDC        RFV       TGB       UJM        14789     
2    EDC        RFV       TGB       UJM        22225
```

But I want to get result like this...

```
IDs  Column_A  Column_B  Column_C  Column_D   Column_E  
1    EDC        RFV       TGB       UJM        14789     
2                                              22225
```

So how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 4):

Don't do this in SQL. In fact, I don't even think it is a good idea in Excel. By removing the values, you lose the ability to do things like filter on the column values or create pivot tables.

You *can* do this in SQL. One simple method uses `lag()`:

```
select . . .,
       (case when lag(column_a) over (order by id) = column_a then NULL
             else column_a
        end) as column_a,
       . . .
```

But just because you can do it doesn't mean that you should.

Comment: It give me warning as "  'lag' is not a recognized built-in function name". Actually I am using SQL SERVER 2008

Comment: LAG was introduced in SQL Server 2012.  You can work around it, but as Gordon Linoff said this is a bad idea.

Comment: Yes ! the Gordon Linoff's point is valid but I just want only show data in such format. Here is no require any filtration.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method to use for SQL 2008, using `ROW_NUMBER()` with some partitions instead of `LAG`.  Note that the `LAG` solution should be more efficient (and readable) if you have access to 2012+.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (IDs int,Column_A char(3), Column_B char(3), Column_C char(3),Column_D char(3),Column_E int)

insert @tbl
VALUES 
(1,'EDC','RFV','TGB','UJM',14789)
,(2,'EDC','RFV','TGB','UJM',22225)
,(3,'EDC','RFV','TGB','UJM',22222)
,(4,'ECD','RFV','TGB','UJM',22222)


select IDs
        ,(case when ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY Column_A order by ids) <> 1 then NULL
             else column_a
            end) as column_a
            ,(case when ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY Column_B order by ids) <> 1 then NULL
             else column_B
            end) as column_b
            ,(case when ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY Column_C order by ids) <> 1 then NULL
             else column_c
            end) as column_c
            ,(case when ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY Column_D order by ids) <> 1 then NULL
             else column_D
            end) as column_D
        ,Column_E
FROM @tbl
```

Input:

```
1   EDC     RFV     TGB     UJM     14789
2   EDC     RFV     TGB     UJM     22225
3   EDC     RFV     TGB     UJM     22222
4   ECD     RFV     TGB     UJM     22222
```

Output:

```
1   EDC     RFV     TGB     UJM     14789
2   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    22225
3   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    22222
4   ECD     NULL    NULL    NULL    22222
```

But again, this is likely to cause more problems than it solves.  I would consider whether it would make more sense to pivot/unpivot or otherwise rearrange the data, perhaps to effectively show a list of IDs for each of Column_A/B/C/D.